# 301 Moved Permanently on post ajax requests in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, serve

I upload a laravel project on server;
When I run all the ajax post request request run like this:

```
Request URL: http://example.com/user/register/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
```

Then this run:

```
Request URL: http://example.com/user/register
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error (from disk cache)
```

Post method change to get method and return error;
How can I solve this?!

I try `php artisan cache:clear php artisan config:clear php artisan view:clear`
But also return error

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the answer. put here to help the others.
It take so time of me. The problem was so simple.
I just remove the backslash from end of url of each post actions.

For example `/user/register/` must change to `/user/register` :|

And cache of the browser must be clear for each page.

Comment: Thanks. So much of time wasted, :( do you know why an ending / makes such a problem?

Comment: No. I don't know why that makes problem @user12414491

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case put backslash in ajax url.

Comment: omg, how did i ran into this after so many years of laravel... i feel stupid :-(

Comment: Is it possible to fix that in the back?

Comment: By default, Laravel's routing configuration ignores trailing slashes. So if there's a mismatch between the URL you're requesting and the route you've defined (e.g., the route is defined as user/register but you're requesting user/register/), Laravel might be trying to "correct" the URL by redirecting

Comment: I found this issue when I was testing in the server, its call the url but its redirected to url without slash, not its ok. thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't know how can i thanks to

Answer (score 5):

In my case, It was redirecting from `http` to `https` make sure your end domain with the exact domain headers.

Check if your domain is placed on `http` or on `https` and match it with the source of the request like with POSTMAN request or Browser Request.

Comment: in my case it was http to https chnage, and I didn't considered it. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

In my case for uploading file, my route was same as public directory -> Route::POST('**upload/data**', [UploadDataController::class, 'upload'])->name('uploadData');

On my public folder:
public/**upload/data**

So I changed the route as **upload/uploadData** and its perfectly fine!